# Where is the Word Wrap shortcut in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Where is the word-wrap icon to toggle back and forth in Visual Studio 2010? I want it in the toolbar or have a shortcut for it.

I see the option in the tools dialog box, but I switch back and forth constantly. I shouldn't have to dig through deep options to toggle this option on and off. Most editors have this option, but for some crazy reason, I can't find it in Visual Studio here...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't find a solution online, and word wrap isn't even showing up in the program's help menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I toggle word wrap in Visual Studio.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315485/how-can-i-toggle-word-wrap-in-visual-studio-net)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can add the word wrap to any toolbar or menu via the Customize functionality in Visual Studio. You need to use the Edit > Toggle Word Wrap command. Here's how you can add it to a new toolbar.

1. Right-click the toolbar and click Customize in the menu.
2. In the Customize dialog click on the new button to create a new toolbar.
3. Give the toolbar a name and click OK.
4. Click on the Commands tab and click on the Toolbar radio button, then select the toolbar you just named.
5. Click on the Add Command button.
6. The Add Command dialog will appear and select the Edit selection in the Categories list box. Then select the Toggle Word Wrap command in the Commands List Box. Click OK to close the dialog.

Comment: Thank you SO much Jorriss! I greatly appreciate your detailed steps and help! This totally made my work day :)

Comment: You can also do this to add the Toggle Word Wrap button to an existing toolbar, without having to create a new toolbar. I added the button to the Text Editor toolbar, for example.

Answer (score 41):

In the default keyboard mapping scheme the Edit.ToggleWordWrap command has the shortcut Ctrl+E, Crtl+W predefined for the Text Editor.

Comment: The same goes for VS 2012 as well.

Comment: Thank you! I hit this key combination by accident (was trying to hit Ctrl-W to select a word and missed, hitting Ctrl-E first) and then wondered what the heck happened to my editor!!